# java.lang.NullPointerException - android.content.ContextWrapper.getDir while creating directory from service

Tags: android, android-context

I want to create directory in application folder from background service. I have used getDir to create a directory. I am sending service context to create directory to DataManager. Also I have confirmed that I am not receiving null context for this. But I have got crash on "`ctx.getDir("Application_Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`" line.

```
private File systemDir;
private File dataDir;
public DataManager(Context ctx) {
    try{
    Log.e("xlogger", "DataManager Context : "+ctx);     
    systemDir = ctx.getDir("Application_Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    dataDir = new File(systemDir, "Data/");
    if(!dataDir.exists()){          
        dataDir.mkdir();
    }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("xlogger", "DataManager Exception : "+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}
```

Crash Report:

```
02-27 13:46:13.100: D/xlogger(4762): DataManager Context = com.MyApp.engine.MyService@4055ad38  
02-27 13:46:13.110: E/xlogger(4762): DataManager Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 13:46:13.110: E/xlogger(4762):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getDir(ContextWrapper.java:198)
02-27 13:46:13.110: E/xlogger(4762):    at com.MyApp.utils.DataManager.<init>(DataManager.java:30)
02-27 13:46:13.110: E/xlogger(4762):    at com.MyApp.communication.MyAppClient.getRulesXML(MyAppClient.java:867)
02-27 13:46:13.110: E/xlogger(4762):    at com.MyApp.engine.MyService$5.doInBackground(MyService.java:862)
02-27 13:46:13.110: E/xlogger(4762):    at com.MyApp.engine.MyService$5.doInBackground(MyService.java:1)
02-27 13:46:13.110: E/xlogger(4762):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-27 13:46:13.110: E/xlogger(4762):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
02-27 13:46:13.110: E/xlogger(4762):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
02-27 13:46:13.110: E/xlogger(4762):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
02-27 13:46:13.110: E/xlogger(4762):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
02-27 13:46:13.110: E/xlogger(4762):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Help highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @StefanBe that dosen't relate with the exception

Answer (score 0):

getDir() or openFileOutput() : they create files in data/data// . This will not be available on any non-rooted mobile. So, root the phone or i suggest you to try in EMULATOR in sucj cases.

Else you can go with getExternalFilesDirectory() --> on sdcard but path is Android/data//files/ and its private to app too.
Even these files get deleted after you uninstall that application :-)

Always rate if helped :-)

Comment: getDir() is available for non rooted phones. The files is only available for the app that creates them.